# Debugging sporadic lightdm and network-manager hang

Tags: 16.04, systemd

About 1 in 10 times I boot, I get a black screen with a blinking cursor.  I then have to do Ctrl+Alt+F1, Log in and do "service lightdm restart" and my graphical desktop comes back.

Probably 1 in 5 times after I log in my Wifi does not connect. Then I do "service network-manager restart" and a few seconds later it autoconnects to my wifi.

Any way to debug these problems? I think something in systemd is misconfigured and comes up in the wrong order.

Comment: When it works, can you do a `systemd-analyze blame` and also one when it doesn't work (before you correct the problem) and compare and post the differences into your question if there are any and let us know if there arent any neither?

Comment: or post both and I'll do the `diff`?

Comment: I would also suspect something around `systemd`. Because it's mostly successful likely a timing issue that might be solved with changing `before` or `after` targets. I wonder ifremoving and then reinstalling `lightdm` might not solve the problem: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384467

Comment: This was it with the wifi broken: https://pastebin.com/raw/bR9fpwWi
And this was it with everything booting clean: https://pastebin.com/raw/wMhRMqdc
I was looking at it and didn't see much difference.